# How can a custom LayoutInflater be used to modify a string resource during layout?

Tags: android, encryption, layout-inflater

I would like to store an encrypted string in my strings.xml:

```
<string name="secret">ENCRYPTED_STRING</string>
```

and use that encrypted string in a TextView:

```
    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/label"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:textSize="11sp"
            android:enabled="false"
            android:text="@string/secret"
    >
    </TextView>
```

and have that encrypted string automatically decrypted during layout inflation of the TextView.

Is this possible by using some type of custom layoutinflater?  Maybe with a custom attribute as well?

Comment: those strings are read only, maybe you want `SharedPreferences`

Comment: I'm not suggesting to modify the strings in the xml.  Only to have them on-the-fly decrypted before the view is created.

Comment: If you are going to write a custom LayoutInflater to decrypt it, why not just get the string in Java, decrypt it, then set the text on the TextView instead of trying to set it in the XML?

Comment: @Tanis.7x Yes, that is one way.  But I would like an answer for how to also do this during layout inflation.

Comment: @Luksprog that should also work.  But what about more universally?  Not just for TextView but for any view?  How can you intercept any layout and decrypt a string?

Comment: you dont need any custom LayoutInflater: what ypu need instead is to implement LayoutInflater.Factory/LayoutInflater.Factory2 interface

Comment: @pskink can you show how you can decrypt the string using this Factory2 interface?

Comment: read this: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/LayoutInflater.Factory2.html

Comment: @pskink already read the view pages.  And your link is dead.

Comment: what view pages? read Factory/Factory2 documentation

Comment: @pskink There is very little on that reference page.  And no example of how to implement anything regarding Factory2. I'm looking for an answer that would show how you can use this to accomplish decrypting a string prior to layout.

Comment: there is almost no examples in android java docs: you need to play with it a bit, test and experiment by yourself, at least i'm doing so...

Comment: btw when implementing Factory/Factory2 interface you can use LayoutInflater.createView(String name, String prefix, AttributeSet attrs) method